# Android studio issue after upgrading

Tags: android, upgrade, chipmunk

It was very good and nice until Android Studio upgraded to Chipmunk. After that it will only open in administrator mode.
how to fix that?
Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in the past and in my case I ended up solving it by uninstalling and installing the android studio version as administrator

Comment: I did that, but it did not work